# Vue 3 watched property does not update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In the pen i've created, the child component does two things, it watches the props and has a method which emits two values.

The parent handling the emitted values modifies the prop and changes the component. However, the child component never fires its watch event.

[See this pen](https://codepen.io/lilja-the-bold/pen/PobBVKX?editors=1012)

The logs:

```
"Emiting values up"
"Form state listener fired"
"Form state has changed"
"move listener fired"
"activeComponent has changed"
"Foo: About to unmount"
"Foo: Unmounted"
```

I expect between

```
"Form state listener fired"
"Form state has changed"
```

a log saying `"Foo: formState changed"`.

How come the watcher is not firing?

Answer (score -1):

I built a couple of test components in my Vue 2 CLI sandbox application, but hopefully it will translate enough to Vue 3 to help you solve your problem.  Also, not sure if it is contributing to your problem, but you may want to take a look at this [Event Names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) documentation.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h3>Parent.vue</h3>
    <hr>
    <child :formState="formState" @form-state-event="updateFormState" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child
    },
    data() {
      return {
        formState: 'Initial State'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateFormState(newState) {
        console.log('updateFormState');
        this.formState = newState;
      }
    }
    
  }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Child.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Form State From Parent (Prop):</label>
        <span>{{ dataFormState }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" @click="changeAndEmit">Emit new form state</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      formState: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        dataFormState: this.formState,
        clickCounter: 1
      }
    },
    watch: {
      formState(newValue) {
        this.dataFormState = newValue;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeAndEmit() {
        console.log('Emitting values up')
        this.$emit("form-state-event", "New form state " + this.clickCounter++);
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This is not a solution since it does not have the element of a dynamic component which changes. I suspect that in my original problem the reason the watch event is not firing is because of the dynamic vue component is changing in rapid succession.